# Remove sorting from datatable column on button click event

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to remove sorting from column heading but its give me the below error. `table1.find is not a function`.

I checked many function of datatable but not working any function. I have decleared my DataTable outside from click event. I think table1  initialization issue. But I am stuck.

```
 var table1 = $('#table1').DataTable( {
        "aaSorting":[[2,'asc']],
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": false,
        "paging": false,
        "jQueryUI":true,
        'sDom' : '<"top">tip',
        "language": {
            "zeroRecords": "No record."
        },

        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 9
        },

        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 0,
            "orderable": false,
            "width":"8px"
            },

            {
            "targets": 1,
            "orderable": false,
            "width":"80px"
            },
            {
            "targets": 2,

            "width":"150px"
            },
            {
            "targets": 3,
            "width":"100px"
            },
            {
            "targets": 4,
            "width":"30px"
            },

            {
            "targets": 5,
            "width":"50px"
            },
            {
            "targets": 6,
            "width":"40px"
            },
            {
            "targets": 7,
            "width":"50px"
            },

            {
            "targets": 8,
            "width":"60px"

            }]

    });
  -------------------------------------------

 $(document).on("click", "#mybtn", function () {
    //var settings = _table1.fnSettings();
    table1.find("th").off("click.DT");

})
```

Comment: It sounds like `table1` isn't a jQuery object. What does `console.log(table1)` show?

Comment: @user7290573  https://screenshot.net/rykv4io this is the ouput of the console.log(table1).

Comment: Try replacing `table1.find("th")` with `$('#table1').find("th")`.

Comment: Not happening any thing. Means sorting still exist. but error is gone

Comment: I want to remove sorting

Comment: Surely that's just an option you need to set during initialisation? Have you checked https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable ?

Comment: I want to enable and disable sorting by click event

Comment: Try `$('#table1').find('th').off('click')` instead of `click.DT` - this works for me in a Codepen.